# Multi-threading best practices

Tags: multithreading, synchronization

I have an application I've written in C#, although any similar language would apply here.

The application has the job of drawing a graphical scene to a window on a Form in real-time based on data it receives over various UDP and TCP sockets. Each UDP and TCP connection uses its own thread: these threads each modify various objects in memory which in turn modify the graphical display. I also have a user interface thread which is capable of receiving user events (button clicks, etc) which in turn modify those same objects and the display. Finally, I also have many timers that I fire which launch their own threads which modify those same objects and the display.

The objects in memory that are being modified consist of about 15 different classes.

Everything works pretty reliably, but with all of those different classes being modified by different threads, I've had to add a lot of synchronization locks. I've had to look at each class individually to determine which memory might be altered by more than one thread.

It seems very easy in this situation to miss one of those spots: to forget to add synchronization somewhere it's needed.

I'm curious as to whether others would implement this the way I did, or if there's some more elegant way: perhaps somehow putting all of the modification of class A on its own thread or something?

(P.S. I'm deathly afraid of asking a question here after things didn't go so well the first time. But I don't think my query here is super-obvious so I'm hoping you won't either. ;o)

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is no straight-forward answer for this.

I have helped other to change the design to deal with similar situation.  One of the most commonly used technique is to introduce a better abstraction.

For example, Assume that you have multiple thread that needs to update a Map containing Users, and another Set containing active user, instead of having locks for the User Map and Active User Set and have your threads acquire the locks manually, I'll suggest introducing an abstraction call UserRepository, in which contains the User map and Active User Set. UserRepository will provide some business-meaningful methods for other to manipulate the UserRepository.  Locks are acquired in the methods of UserRepository, instead by the caller explicitly.

From my past experience, over 80% of complicated synchronization can be greatly simplified by having better design like the above mentioned example.

There are also other technique possible.  For example, if the update is ok to do asynchronously, instead of having your threads update the resources directly, you may create command objects and put in a producer-consumer queue, and have a dedicate thread performing the update.

Also sometimes it is much easier to handle to have fewer locks.  For example, when updating several resources, instead of having one lock for each resource, we can see the update as a whole action, and use only one lock for the coordination between threads.  Of course it will increase contention, but there are cases that contention is not a big problem but we want maintainability instead.

I believe there are lots of other way to deal with similar situation, I am just sharing some of my previous experiences (which worked :P )

Comment: Thanks so much for the robust answer. This is a really good discussion of the topic.